# Computing a rank

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Consider positive, i.e. non-zero, integers $n<m$, an $n$-dimensional vector space with $v_1,...,v_m\in V$ and elements $\alpha_1,...\alpha_m\in V^\ast$.

We define a matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ with $a_{ij}=\alpha_i(v_j)$.

Why do we have $\text{rk}~A\leq n$?

Comment: What is your definition of rank?

Comment: You can choose your favourite one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select a basis $(w_1,\dots,w_n)$ of $V$.  Write
$$
v_j = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{jk} w_k
$$
We note that the $j$th column of $A$ is given by
$$
(\alpha_1(v_j),\dots,\alpha_n(v_j)) = \sum_{k=1}^n c_{jk} (\alpha_1(w_k),\dots,\alpha_n(w_k))
$$
Thus, the vectors $(\alpha_1(w_k),\dots,\alpha_n(w_k))$ (for $k = 1,\dots,n$) span the column space of $A$.  Thus, the dimension of the column space (and hence the rank of $A$) is at most $n$.